# Qualifying multiple rules with one fact

Tags: rule-engine

I am trying to make a system which evaluates rules based on transactions.

For example;

Henry bought sth for 500 dollars, there may be 2 rules which Henry qualifies at the end of this transaction.

1. if somebody spends 200 dollars, reward free shipment.
2. if somebody spends 500 dollars, reward %10 discount.

Please correct me if i am wrong, Rete algorithm defines each rule as leaves of a tree meaning that a new transaction will qualify only one rule. If that is the case, what can be a solution for the above scenario.

My second question is, I want customer to define the rules from a web interface using a TaskUI. For example, first screen lets user to enter the criteria (spend > 500), second screen lets to choose reward (discount %10). I understand that facts(transactions) can be inserted to knowledge base at run-time but is this also applicable for rules? Most of the rule engines read rules from files etc.. Is it possible to create rules like the above scenario and evaluate them during run-time.

Your comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In then rete algorithm if there are multiple rules which are applicable, one will be selected and executed. This will be repeated as long as there are applicable rules. Unless one rule invalidates the conditions of another rule, all rules that are satisfied will be applied.

Whether you can dynamically add rules to the rule engine depends on which rule engine you're using. Some support this and some do not..